# CheckInstall on CentOS

Tags: centos, rhel, make, source, checkinstall

I am attempting to make CheckInstall on a clean version of CentOS however I am having difficulty, I receive the following error:

```
[root@host checkinstall-1.6.2]# make
for file in locale/checkinstall-*.po ; do \
        case ${file} in \
            locale/checkinstall-template.po)  ;; \
            *) \
                out=`echo $file | sed -s 's/po/mo/'` ; \
                msgfmt -o ${out} ${file} ; \
                if [ $? != 0 ] ; then \
                    exit 1 ; \
                fi ; \
            ;; \
        esac ; \
    done    
/bin/sh: line 5: msgfmt: command not found
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

How can fix these dependency errors? Without using 'yum' if at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the `gettext` package.

```
gettext-0.17-16.el6.x86_64 : GNU libraries and utilities for producing multi-lingual messages
Repo        : installed
Matched from:
Other       : Provides-match: /usr/bin/msgfmt
```